# How to hide a toggled div and show another in its place

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to put together a menu for a theme I'm working on however I'm having trouble getting part of it to work. Specifically, I want to be able to click on a link and have a div slide down and then fade in, then click another link and have that div fade and slide out then a new div slide and fade in its place. At the moment I have it working when hiding a div using the same link to show it, but different links just pile divs on top of each other.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
jQuery.fn.fadeThenSlideToggle = function () {
    if (this.is(":hidden")) {
        return this.slideDown(500, "linear").fadeTo(500, 1, "linear");
    } else {
        return this.fadeTo(500, 0, "linear").slideUp(500, "linear");
    }
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#toggleabout').click(function () {
        $('#about').fadeThenSlideToggle();
        return false;
    });
    $('#toggleprojects').click(function () {
        $('#projects').fadeThenSlideToggle();
        return false;
    });
    $('#toggleconnect').click(function () {
        $('#connect').fadeThenSlideToggle();
        return false;
    });
    $('#toggleexchange').click(function () {
        $('#exchange').fadeThenSlideToggle();
        return false;
    });
    $('#toggleextras').click(function () {
        $('#extras').fadeThenSlideToggle();
        return false;
    });
    $('#togglesearch').click(function () {
        $('#search').fadeThenSlideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

With a previous menu I designed I used something like this:

```
$('#toggleconnect').click(function () {
    $(".menubox:not(#connect)").slideUp(500, "linear");
    $('#connect').delay(600).slideToggle(500, "linear");
    return false;
});
```

This works fine when only calling on a single effect however the complexity of what I want to do here seems to break this. I've tried a few things but nothing seems to work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

### [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/GrgCk)

Comment: I added a pen, it seems to work there.  What's the problem with it?  What do you mean by "pilling"?

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hEQfd/4/

Comment: You could condense all those `click fadeThenSlideToggle()` handlers to one using a class and data attrib.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks, that's what I wanted to do.

Comment: @SovereignAnarchei I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery.fn.fadeThenSlideToggle = function(opts) {
    opts = opts || {};

    var hide = function(el, complete){
        var p1, p2;
        el.finish();
        p1= el.fadeTo(500, 0, "linear").promise();
        p2 = el.slideUp(500, "linear").promise();
        $.when(p1, p2).done(complete)
    }
    var show  = function(el, complete){
        var p1, p2;    
        el.finish();
        p1 = el.slideDown(500, "linear").promise();
        p2 = el.fadeTo(500, 1, "linear").promise();
        $.when(p1, p2).done(opts.complete)
    }

    if (this.is(":hidden")) {
        if(opts.divs){
            hide(opts.divs.filter(':visible').not(this), $.proxy(function(){
                show(this, opts.complete)
            }, this))
        } else {
            show(this, opts.complete)
        }
    } else {
        hide(this, opts.complete)
    }


    return this;
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divs = $('#about, #projects, #connect, #exchange, #extras, #search').hide()
    $('#toggleabout').click(function() {
        $('#about').fadeThenSlideToggle({
            divs: divs
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#toggleprojects').click(function() {
        $('#projects').fadeThenSlideToggle({
            divs: divs
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#toggleconnect').click(function() {
        $('#connect').fadeThenSlideToggle({
            divs: divs
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#toggleexchange').click(function() {
        $('#exchange').fadeThenSlideToggle({
            divs: divs
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#toggleextras').click(function() {
        $('#extras').fadeThenSlideToggle({
            divs: divs
        });
        return false;
    });
    $('#togglesearch').click(function() {
        $('#search').fadeThenSlideToggle({
            divs: divs
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hEQfd/4/)